# Quando utilizar linhas em branco em um programa Python?

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação, indentação, pep8

Pular linhas é um dos aspectos que tornam um programa bem indentado? Se sim, qual o critério utilizado para pular linhas?

Comment: Linhas em branco demais tornam o código ilegível. E linhas em branco de menos também

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Python Enhancement Proposal

Essas são documentos de design mantidos pela comunidade Python e mantidos no [GitHub](https://github.com/python/peps) que definem *guidelines* para melhor utilização da linguagem e seus recursos. Essas definições são bem argumentadas, definem um postulado e o embasam com as justificativas da adoção desse documento. Elas são numeradas, então é comum ler PEP 1, PEP 5, PEP 8 ou PEP 500.

- [python.org: "What is a PEP?"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/#id31) (direto da PEP 1)

Uma das PEPs ditas essenciais a leitura do programador Python é a oitava. A [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) é um guia de estilização de código. Minha resposta foi formulada em cima dessa PEP, que é uma documentação de alta credibilidade.

Nessa PEP também foram definidas [*guidelines*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out) da indentação de código Python.

#### Quantos espaços ao indentar?

É sintaticamente obrigatório que você indente o seu código Python. A PEP diz para que você utilize quatro espaços por nível de indentação.

```
print("olá")
if foo:
    # quatro espaços
```

#### Tabs e/ou espaços

Espaços são preferíveis. Tenha consistência: se fizer com tabs, faça TUDO com tabulações. O contrário também é válido. O Python 3 nem permite que você misture tabulações e espaços, assim você terá:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

#### Linhas de continuação de código (hanging indentation)

Hanging indentation é quando todas as linhas do parágrafo estão indentadas menos a primeira.

Faça:

```
# Aligned with opening delimiter.
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
                         var_three, var_four)
```

Não faça:

```
# Arguments on first line forbidden when not using vertical alignment.
foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
    var_three, var_four)
```

A guideline dos quatro espaços é opcional nesse tipo de indentação. Pode fazer:

```
foo = long_function_name(
  var_one, var_two,
  var_three, var_four)
```

Limite qualquer linha de código a 79 caracteres. Para onde não há jeito, utilize o caractere de escape assim:

```
with open('/path/to/some/file/you/want/to/read') as file_1, \
     open('/path/to/some/file/being/written', 'w') as file_2:
    file_2.write(file_1.read())
```

#### Quebras de linha

A PEP 8 diz que você deve ter duas linhas em branco entre os statements de `import` e o restante do código.

```
import x
import y
import z


def foo()
    pass
```

E duas quebras entre cada função definida.

```
def a()
    pass


def b()
    pass
```

Outra PEP que diz sobre quebras de linha é a PEP 257, que define convenções de documentação de código Python. Lá diz:

> There's no blank line either before or after the docstring.

Portanto, faça isso:

```
def alo():
    """Retorna um alô"""
    return 'alô'
```

São muitas recomendações definidas nessa PEP. Existe uma ferramenta para verificar se seu código está dentro da PEP 8, baseado no pep8.py. Veja **[PEP8 online check](http://pep8online.com/)**.

Answer (score 6):

Python possui um guia de estilos que é muito utilizado pela comunidade e nela há uma seção sobre linhas em branco no código: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code: Blank Lines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines). Abaixo citarei o texto original, em inglês, e comentarei logo mais abaixo.

> *Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.*

*Cercar* definições de funções de nível superior e classes com dois espaços em branco. Ou seja, sempre que for definir uma nova função de nível superior ou uma classe, deixe um espaçamento de duas linhas.

```py
import json


def stringify(obj):
    return json.loads(obj)


def show(string):
    print(string)


class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

> *Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a single blank line.*

Sempre que definir um novo método em uma classe, deixe um espaçamento de uma linha em torno do mesmo.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def walk(distance):
        ...

    def speak(text):
        ...
```

> *Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).*

Linhas em branco podem ser utilizadas (com moderação) para separar grupos de funções relacionadas e podem ser omitidas entre várias declarações de uma linha. Atribuição de variáveis, atributos em um objeto, definições de estruturas *lambdas*, etc, são, geralmente, estruturas de uma linha e, neste caso, a linha em branco pode ser omitida.

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3

distance = lambda x, y, z: x + y + z
square = lambda x: x**2
```

> *Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.*

Use linhas em branco em funções, com moderação, para separar seções lógicas. Por exemplo, atribuição de variáveis, validação, etc.

```
def status(age):

    output = "baby"  # atribuição

    if age < 0:  # validação
        raise Exception("The age must be a non-negative number")

    if 2 < age < 18:  # lógica
        output = "young"
    elif age < 60:
        output = "adult"
    else:
        output = "old"

    return output  # retorno
```

Em qualquer outro caso não citado fica completamente a seu critério. Na verdade, isso são só recomendações, você não precisa obrigatoriamente seguí-las. Se seguir, seu código será melhor recebido pela comunidade, pois será muito mais fácil entendê-lo.

Answer (score 3):

Indentar é o recuo do texto em relação a sua margem, ou seja, se antes de escrevermos uma instrução, utilizamo 4 espaçamentos da margem esquerda até a instrução propriamente dita, podemos dizer que a indentação utilizada possui 4 espaços.

```
#coding: utf-8

print(nivel 1)#primeiro nível hierárquico

if(True):
    print(nível 2)#segundo nível hierárquico
```

Mais informações: http://excript.com/python/indentacao-python.html

Comment: E sobre pular linhas?