# Indentação em Python

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação

Gostaria de saber onde eu poderia colocar espaços em brancos para separar partes do código de acordo com a PEP8.

```
q = int(input('Quantos números sua sequência tem?(3 ou mais)'))
if q < 3:
    while True:
        q = int(input('Quantos números sua sequência tem?(3 ou mais)'))
        if q >= 3:
            break
seq = [int(input()) for c in range(0, q)]
x = y = 0
n = []
while y < q:
    if x not in seq: 
        while True: 
            x += 1 
            if x in seq:
                break
    else:
        if x in seq: 
            n.append(x)
            x += 1
            y += 1
    if y == q:
        break
print(n)
```

Comment: Acho que só a [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) importa e parece estar tudo certo, só bati o olho.

Comment: Tinha dúvida se existia algum desvio na PEP, mas como pelo que parece não existe, eu editei a pergunta e foquei na minha segunda dúvida.

Comment: Mas você já não perguntou isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/249584/101

Comment: Ainda me restaram algumas dúvidas que acho que só seriam resolvidas de um forma mais prática, demonstrando no código.

Comment: Sei lá, neste código está tudo certo, nem tem o que responder.

Comment: Mesmo já tendo feito uma pergunta sobre o tema, percebi que depois de um tempo ainda tinha algumas dúvidas que não consegui esclarecer através da última pergunta, por isso fiz essa nova pergunta para complementar a outra com um exemplo mais prático e menos teórico.

Comment: @LucasSouza Quais são essas dúvidas, mais especificamente? Por que essa pergunta aqui é sobre onde devem ser espaços no código, e isso já está (muito bem) respondido na outra pergunta que você fez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

você tem mais coisas com que se preocupar no código do que o espaçamento de linhas.

Código é sobre ter funções - e se for aplicáel ao problema, ter classes e métodos - um "programa" jogado sem sequer uma função é algo que pode ser feito e vai funcionar - mas quase ninguém no mundo vai ligar se está no "estilo correto": ele não apresenta o mais básico elemento para reuso de código e organização real da informação  que é o uso de funções. Se tem uma, 3 ou 20 linhas em branco onde não deveria não faz diferença.

A PEP 8, que é apenas um docuemnto de sugestão de *estilo* de código, embora código formatado estritamente de acordo com ela fique sim mais bonito de olhar, é especialmente draconiana linhas em branco.

Basicamente, você pode deixar uma linha em branco onde quiser no seu código. Mas apenas uma. Se pular duas linhas vai estar violando a convenção de estilo. E aí, é claro que vale o bom senso: você deixa linhas em branco quando uma parte do código for estar lidando com um "tema" ou fazendo algo diferente. Pode ser, por exemplo, uma após o input, uma antes do while (mas não o while que está dentro do if - ele já está visualmente separado do código em volta por iniciar um bloco). E possivelemnte uma depois do while  e antes do último print, nesse código. Mas ele, de novo, não é representativo de um programa "real".

Já funções e classes no corpo do objeto devem ter exatamente duas linhas em branco antes e duas depois de sua declaração (métodos dentro de uma classe devem estar separados apenas por uma linha em branco, no entanto).

E é basicamente isso. Como seu exemplo de código não tem sequer uma função, não tem como "mostrar de forma mais prática". Agora, insisto que se ainda não é da sua natureza ao programar separar tudo em funções, é nesse ponto que você deve se focar se quiser aperfeiçoar seu estilo de programação.